# 502 Bad Gateway. Flask, Gunicorn inside Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, flask

I'm made a flask app and now im trying to deploy it using docker. Im getting 502 bad gateway error. the terminal log is clear i.e. gunicornworks fine.
nginx.conf file

```
upstream flask-app {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD /etc/init.d/nginx start && gunicorn -w 3 app:app --timeout 900 --preload
```

Terminal

```
Starting nginx: nginx.
[2023-03-18 06:39:54 +0000] [19] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-03-18 06:39:54 +0000] [19] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (19)
[2023-03-18 06:39:54 +0000] [19] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-03-18 06:39:54 +0000] [25] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be incorrect nginx configuration, you can check it running

```
$ nginx -t
```

The problem may be the missing protocol in the URL at `proxy_pass`, I believe it should be

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

Other than that you try checking nginx logs.

Comment: Well still it is not working! `server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}`